# node twitter npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I've installed node-twitter via npm and have created an index.js file with the code below.  When I run node index.js in the console I'm not getting any response.  I've included my own keys and secrets so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
});

client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'nyc'},  function(stream){
  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
    console.log(tweet.text);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're connecting to one of Twitter's streaming endpoints, so you will only see updates if someone posts a tweet with the text 'nyc' in it at that precise moment.

I suspect this is not your intention, and you instead wish to search for the most recent tweets containing the text 'nyc', as below:

```
client.get('/search/tweets.json?q=nyc', function(error, tweets, response){
  if(error) throw error;
  console.log(tweets);
});
```

The Twitter search API documentation is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).  If you actually *do* wish to stream tweets, I recommend using something like forever.js to keep your script running long enough to listen for tweets and output them.

Edit:  Since you would like to stream the tweets as they come in, you can use forever.js to keep your script running, as below:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('twitter.js', {
    max: 1,
    silent: false,
    args: []
});

child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('twitter.js has exited after 3 restarts');
});

child.start();
```

Where twitter.js is the file posted in the question.  If you want to search backwards or forwards from a specified time, you can find details on how to do so in the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines).

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out how to get tweets at that moment and moving forward.

Comment: I've edited my answer above with an example of how to keep your script running using forever.js.  Hope this helps!